# pyOpenSSL NotImplementedError Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-reporting-api

I'm trying to download some data using Google Analytics Reporting API V4.

Inside my `lib/` folder (on the GAE project) I have `pyOpenSSL` and all its dependencies.

Locally, in my virtualenv, it works fine.

That's the error I'm getting:

```html
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: ###############

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/1.394185263495829842/lib/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/1.394185263495829842/lib/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/1.394185263495829842/polls/views.py" in index
  27.     return HttpResponse(json.dumps(we.atualizacao_diaria()))

File "lib/workers/worker_estacio.py" in atualizacao_diaria
  41.         return self.atualizar_periodo(f_date, f_date)

File "lib/workers/worker_estacio.py" in atualizar_periodo
  47.         c_ga_estacio = ConectorEstacioGA()

File "lib/workers/conectores/conector_ga.py" in __init__
  50.         credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, KEY_FILE_LOCATION, scopes=SCOPES)

File "lib/oauth2client/service_account.py" in from_p12_keyfile
  345.             token_uri=token_uri, revoke_uri=revoke_uri)

File "lib/oauth2client/service_account.py" in _from_p12_keyfile_contents
  300.             raise NotImplementedError(_PKCS12_ERROR)

Exception Type: NotImplementedError at /
Exception Value: 
This library only implements PKCS#12 support via the pyOpenSSL library.
Either install pyOpenSSL, or please convert the .p12 file
to .pem format:
    $ cat key.p12 | \
    >   openssl pkcs12 -nodes -nocerts -passin pass:notasecret | \
    >   openssl rsa > key.pem
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Base on your error have you already tried changing the file type to .p12 file? As suggested in the error report? Also check this [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) documentation for further information.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried. I think this is pretty much an app engine problem, the whole thing works fine in my test machine, it breaks down when I deploy to production. I'm not saying app engine has a problem, I'm saying I'm missing something about how to use pyOpenSSL there :)

Answer (score 14):

I have no clue about how to install the proper libs in GAE for use the .p12 key.

I solved it using the .json key which is available for download in the same place as the .p12:

[image]

Then, it is important to change the `ServiceAccountCredentials` constructor:

> `credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, KEY_FILE_LOCATION_P12, scopes=SCOPES)`

Must be replaced by:

> `credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(KEY_FILE_LOCATION_JSON, scopes=SCOPES)`

I hope that might help somebody :)

Comment: This is the best and most up-to-date solution, I've tried installing pyOpenSSL Library as suggested by the debugger but it didn't work either so I used @Thiago's solution and it worked fine.